# Must pass urls in quotes

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh, string, arguments

I'm trying pass a URL to `mpv` for it to play it as a network stream.

This can be done in `bash` with the following syntax:

```
$ mpv http://myvideosite.com
```

However, `zsh` wants to evaluate the URL as (presumably) a file path. Running

```
% mpv http://myvideosite.com
```

gets the following response:

```
zsh: no matches found: http://myvideosite.com
```

and a return code of 1.

Running

```
% mpv "http://myvideosite.com"
```

executes as expected.

Does `zsh` not treat arguments as strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you've inadvertently trimmed the important part of your command lines out here: the URLs in question contain a `?` character (or a `*`). `?` and `*` are special glob matching characters to the shell. `?` matches a single character in a filename, and `*` matches many. When `zsh` says:

```
zsh: no matches found: http://myvideosite.com?video=123
```

it's telling you that there's no file called `http://myvideosite.com?video=123` accessible from the current directory.

In zsh, by default, a failed expansion like this is an error, but in Bash it isn't: the failed pattern is just left as an argument exactly as it was written. zsh's behaviour is safer, in that you can't write a command that secretly doesn't do what you meant because a file was missing, but you can change it to have the Bash behaviour if you want:

```
setopt nonomatch
```

The [`NOMATCH` option is on by default](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NOMATCH), and causes the errors you were seeing. If you disable it with `setopt nonomatch` then any failed glob expansions will be left intact on the command line:

```
$ echo foo?bar
zsh: no matches found: foo?bar
$ setopt nonomatch
$ echo foo?bar
foo?bar
```

This will resolve your original use case. In general it will be better to quote arguments with special characters, though, in order to avoid any mistakes where a file happens to exist with a corresponding name, or doesn't exist when you thought it did.